# left join with three tables

Tags: sql, left-join

Can anyone explain what will happen in following scenario?

```
SELECT * 
FROM A,
     B 
LEFT JOIN C 
       ON B.FIELD1=C.FIELD1 
WHERE A.FIELD1='SOME VALUE'
```

Here table A and table B are not joined with any condition. So my doubt is what kind of join will be applied between A and B?

Comment: Do **not** mix implicit joins and explicit joins - regardless of which DBMS you are actually using.

Comment: Could you tell me, That what is C and do you have Two table with name (A and B) or Three

Comment: Hi Arif, Here A, B and C are tables.. I just gave it for example..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A cross join (cartesian product, if you prefer) will be applied between the results of A and B left join C: each row in the first set will be tied to each row in the second set.

Answer (score 0):

A cross join applies, If you don't used a join condition, get irrelavent results also.

Answer (score 0):

Please try it

```
SELECT * FROM A INNER JOIN B ON  A.IDCOLUMND=B.IDCOLUMN  LEFT JOIN C ON B.FIELD1=C.FIELD1
```